# Soapui websocket transport testing

Tags: websocket, wsdl, soapui

I tried to add `WebSocket Transport Plugin for soapUI` following: https://github.com/pbielicki/soapui-websocket-transport

Tried to use the demo: ws://echo.websocket.org, by entering it as a wsdl.
But I got the error:

> Wed Dec 17 09:51:14 IST 2014:ERROR:Failed to load url [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/SmartBear/soapUI-Pro-4.5.1/bin/ws:/echo.websocket.org]

How to send the soap message ?
It looks like the `soapui` is trying to find the wsdl in the local computer.

Comment: Jacky Sedi, I have just tried as per the question. Not sure how to run `ws://echo.websocket.org`. By the way, the `github` link shows it is tested on _SoapUI 5.x_, so tried in SoapUI 5.2.1 free edition. And yes, regarding your question that `soapUI`  at least needs a wsdl, may be for time being add any sample wsdl and then `edit the request and endpoint`, then try sending request. Looks it gets the response. Please [this](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=95809914254844035757) screen shot showing from **soapui and browser** with same details.

Comment: By the way, used [this link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html) to create a websocket as I could not use in the way you mentioned `echo` example.

Comment: I'm getting an error also:
10:17:48,331 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry$MissingTransportException: Missing transport for protocol [ws]], see error log for details

Comment: This project referred do apparently doesn't support WSS (secured) only WS (unsecured).  Anyone know of a SOAPUI plugin that supports WSS also?

Comment: apparently this is only for the free version.  For the commercial version of SOAPUI you need this plugin:
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Is-there-a-plan-to-support-Websocket-WS-and-WSS-conenction-in/td-p/121244